# VB.Net Paragraph Space

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, paragraph

So my code is like this :

```
richtextbox1.text = x1.text + x2.text (x's are labels)
```

And the result is like this :

```
x1x2
```

Expected Output :

```
x1
x2
```

Comment: `richtextbox1.text = x1.text & Environment.Newline & x2.text` and then read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NewLine Char to put extra line between two string.

```
richTextBox1.Text = string1 + System.Environment.NewLine + string2
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I am not good at this but this worked for me:
1. declare **string 1** and **string 2** just before the **if statement** like this using **Dim**:

```
    Dim string1 = "I am teacher."
    Dim string2 = "I like my students."
    If TextBox1.Text = "write here the word that you want to search" Then
    RichTextBox1.Text = "I am teacher." + System.Environment.NewLine + "I like my students."
    End If
```

- I am teacher. is an example of a paragraph1
- I like my students. is an example of a paragraph2

  2. Now here is the if statement with the two paragraphs above:

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
RichTextbox1.Text = x1.Text & " " &
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.